# Cycles smoke not responding to wind

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, force-fields

I made some dense smoke in cycles with the Quick Smoke simulation. I want the smoke to be blown to the left of the scene as if it's coming out of a smokestack, so I added a wind force field. No effect. I turned up the strength, still no effect. I even added another wind force field, yet the smoke still stubbornly rises straight up.

How can I get the smoke to respond to wind?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Wind Falloff

The force field in the scene is being affected by a high dampening due to the simulation of gravity introduced by the **Falloff** settings you are using. The wind is now acting as if it was dragged down by a strong force that is currently erasing its influence on the smoke.

[image]

If it is suitable for your project, my suggestion would be to simply come back to the default value of **Falloff Power** = 0.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by the force field being on a different layer than the smoke domain.